# Importing multiple CSV to multiple worksheet in a single workbook

Tags: vba, excel, csv

How do I do this? Basically I want my multiple CSV files to be imported to  multiple worksheet but in a single workbook only. Here's my VBA code that I want to loop. I need the loop to query all the CSV in `C:\test\`

```
Sub Macro()
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;C:\test\test1.csv", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "test1"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[This guy](https://sites.google.com/a/madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/merge-functions/csvs-to-sheets) absolutely nailed it. Very concise code and works perfectly for me on 2010. All credit goes to him (Jerry Beaucaire). I found it from a forum [here](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/742348-merge-multiple-csv-files-to-one-xls-with-multiple-tabs.html#post2367007).

```
Option Explicit
Sub ImportCSVs()
'Author:    Jerry Beaucaire
'Date:      8/16/2010
'Summary:   Import all CSV files from a folder into separate sheets
'           named for the CSV filenames

'Update:    2/8/2013   Macro replaces existing sheets if they already exist in master workbook

Dim fPath   As String
Dim fCSV    As String
Dim wbCSV   As Workbook
Dim wbMST   As Workbook

Set wbMST = ThisWorkbook
fPath = "C:\test\"                  'path to CSV files, include the final \
Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'speed up macro
Application.DisplayAlerts = False   'no error messages, take default answers
fCSV = Dir(fPath & "*.csv")         'start the CSV file listing

    On Error Resume Next
    Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
        Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fCSV)                    'open a CSV file
        wbMST.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Delete                       'delete sheet if it exists
        ActiveSheet.Move After:=wbMST.Sheets(wbMST.Sheets.Count)    'move new sheet into Mstr
        Columns.Autofit             'clean up display 
        fCSV = Dir                  'ready next CSV
    Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set wbCSV = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with 2013 (unless I'm missing something.) I copied this script into a macro-enabled Excel workbook (2013) and ran it (with two .csv files in the specified directory). When I ran it, it opened up two new instances Excel (two new workbooks) with a single worksheet in each, and nothing in my original workbook. Does the script need to be updated?

Comment: I'm not likely to have time to investigate, sorry. Please feel welcome to give an updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

Beware, this does not handles errors like you would have a duplicate sheet name if you imported a `csv`.

This uses early binding so you need to Reference `Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime` under *Tools..References* in the `VBE`

```
Dim fs  As New FileSystemObject
Dim fo As Folder
Dim fi As File
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sname As String

Sub loadall()
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Set fo = fs.GetFolder("C:\TEMP\")

    For Each fi In fo.Files
        If UCase(Right(fi.name, 4)) = ".CSV" Then
            sname = Replace(Replace(fi.name, ":", "_"), "\", "-")

            Set ws = wb.Sheets.Add
            ws.name = sname
            Call yourRecordedLoaderModified(fi.Path, ws)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub yourRecordedLoaderModified(what As String, where As Worksheet)
With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & what, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .name = "test1"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Dir` to filter out and run with just the `csv` files

```
Sub MacroLoop()
Dim strFile As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
strFile = Dir("c:\test\*.csv")
Do While strFile <> vbNullString
Set ws = Sheets.Add
With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & "C:\test\" & strFile, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = strFile
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
strFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: The worksheet name doesn't reflect the filename of the CSV file for this code. How do I resolve that?

Comment: I already resolved the filename of worksheet. My new issue is, I'm getting out of memory error. I am importing around 80 CSV files.

Comment: @Dumont On the file name I presume you see I used a variable. On your memory erro, how many CSVs is it importing? Did the other code you accept work given it uses the same import method (but tests each file type first)

Comment: Yes, it gives the same error. I'm importing around 80 CSV files.

Comment: Only 30 CSV out of 80 are imported to excel.

Comment: It's okay now. It seems like the code fails when a CSV has no content. I just added `On Error Resume Next`

Answer (score 2):

I had 183 csv files to condense into one workbook, one worksheet per csv file to facilitate analysis of the data and did not want to manually do this one at a time. I tried the highest rated solution on this question but had the same problem as another user; the csv files would open, but nothing would be inserted to the target workbook. I spent some time and adjusted the code so that it works as in Excel 2016. I haven't tested on older versions. I have not coded in Visual Basic in ages so there's probably a ton of room for improvement in my code, but it worked for me in a pinch. In case anyone happens to stumble upon this question as I did, I'm pasting the code I used below.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ImportCSVs()
'Author:    Jerry Beaucaire
'Date:      8/16/2010
'Summary:   Import all CSV files from a folder into separate sheets
'           named for the CSV filenames

'Update:    2/8/2013   Macro replaces existing sheets if they already exist in master workbook
'Update: base script as seen in: https://sites.google.com/a/madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/merge-functions/csvs-to-sheets
'Update: adjusted code to work in Excel 2016

Dim fPath   As String
Dim fCSV    As String
Dim wbName  As String
Dim wbCSV   As Workbook
Dim wbMST   As Workbook


wbName = "this is a string"
Set wbMST = ThisWorkbook

fPath = "C:\pathOfCSVFiles\"                  'path to CSV files, include the final \
Application.ScreenUpdating = False  'speed up macro
Application.DisplayAlerts = False   'no error messages, take default answers
fCSV = Dir(fPath & "*.csv")         'start the CSV file listing

    On Error Resume Next
    Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
        Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fCSV)                    'open a CSV file
        If wbName = "this is a string" Then 'this is to check if we are just starting out and target workbook only has default Sheet 1
            wbCSV.Sheets.Copy After:=wbMST.Sheets(1) 'for first pass, can leave as is. if loading a large number of csv files and excel crashes midway, update this to the last csv that was loaded to the target workbook
        Else
            wbCSV.Sheets.Copy After:=wbMST.Sheets(wbName) 'if not first pass, then insert csv after last one
        End If

        fCSV = Dir                  'ready next CSV
        wbName = ActiveSheet.Name 'save name of csv loaded in this pass, to be used in the next pass
    Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set wbCSV = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try this, but I'd go with [this](http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=150279):

```
Dim NumFound As Long 
With Application.FileSearch 
    .NewSearch
    .LookIn = "C:\test\"
    .FileName = "*.csv"
    If .Execute() > 0 Then 
        For i = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count
            With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
                "TEXT;" & "C:\test\" & (Application.FileSearch.FoundFiles(i)), Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
                ...
            End With
            Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Next i
    End If
End With
```

Comment: `Application.FileSearch` was deprecated in Office 2007 so this is unlikley to be suitable