# Batch Import XML Files to Excel Workbook (VBA)

Tags: excel, xml, vba, import, batch-processing

Mission: I have a folder of some 90 XML files received weekly that all need consolidated as individual pages in an excel workbook (excel 2016). To make that clear, the resulting workbook should have 90 pages (or however many XML files I need to import that week), with each sheet matching the file name of the XML matched to it.

I have found *several* mentions on how to batch import XMLs into a single sheet or table, but other than the kutools extensions that never work for me, I can't seem to find anything that imports the files as individual sheets.

Is this even possible? I am a complete VBA scrub, but if there's a way to do this that doesn't involve me manually clicking Data -> Get Data -> From File -> From XML File and going through all the dialogues for each individual file, I would love to hear it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Record a macro while performing a single import, then use that as the basis for a loop using (eg) `Dir("C:\yourfolder here\*.xml")`

Comment: Is there a good resource I can read or watch on how exactly to do that? Not the recording bit, because I can do that but like ... the rest of it? I tried putting something together based on this script [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162477) since it's the closest I could find to what I'm doing, but after replacing everything with the (hopefully) relevant lines I took from the macro and running it ... nothing happens. I am deeply at a loss.

Comment: @Damiano my favorite resource is the Chip Pearson site: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Topic.aspx

Comment: The official documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very basic example:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Const FLDR As String = "C:\Tester\tmp\"
    
    Dim f, wb
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    f = Dir(FLDR & "*.xml")
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        Debug.Print(f) 'output filename to Immediate panel
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set wb = Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=FLDR & f, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        wb.Sheets(1).Name = Replace(f, ".xml", "")
        wb.Sheets(1).Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
        wb.Close False
        f = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! For the sake of trying to run it and see what may need changed I loaded this into the sheet, updating the FLDR string with the file path I've put some of the XMLs in but when I run the macro, I'm still getting nothing - not even an error to tell me if I messed something up. I went into VBA (Alt + F11), copied the script, saved it, then in a blank workbook tried to run the macro and got nothing. Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: Are you on a Mac?

Comment: No, I am using a PC.

Comment: Then this should work fine.  If nothing is happening when you run it then it's not finding any xml files in the folder you specified.  Added a debug.print line above - do you see any output?

Comment: I'm not sure why but it's working fine now. In any case, this works for the fundamental import! I do have a question now on whether I can factor in the query (after import, I have one of three options I normally select then hit load while uploading the XML, which filters out some of the data). Running that gives me an error.

In the interest of not bogging this answer down with follow-up questions, is there somewhere I can ping you for help with figuring out where to put with the macro I recorded earlier? Or should I edit the original post with what I have?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with importing XML to Excel using the built-in tools, but I can take a look.  If you drop your email here in a comment I will ping you via email (after which you can delete your comment)