Excel VBA - How do you span a large multi line XML string to many rows or as XML import
Excel VBA - How do you span a large multi line XML string to many rows or as XML import.
I'm interogating a server for information which is responding with the required XML information.
So without truncation I need to either:

Embed the results as an imported XML file.
Populate each row by each line.


Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim authKey As String

authKey = "KEYREMOVED"

Set sht = Sheet1

Dim strUrl As String
    strUrl = <URL>
    Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With hReq
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False
        .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & authKey
        .Send
    End With

    Dim response As String
    response = hReq.ResponseText

    MsgBox response
        
    'Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = response
End Sub

** Using the last command puts all the result into the cell and further truncates.
(Searching the web keeps bringing up doing it via non-vba ways)

Could you show an example of the XML you are importing?

Have you tried saving the response to a file and using (eg) Workbooks.OpenXML(Filename:=yourFileHere, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList) ?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/68537682/478884

@MT1 - Company sensitive info - but I'll see what I can do..

@Tim Williams: What is the best way to save as a file then.. I've provided the code/macro above but still yet to work through all options..  So looking at the above code.. what do you recommend? as saving would be a very good option...

https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+save+string+to+txt+file+site:stackoverflow.com   Plenty of previous posts on this topic here on SO.
