# Bulk importing CSV and choosing delimiter

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm trying to import several CSV files in a Folder in a Workbook and paste each csv file in a seperate worksheet. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12162477/importing-multiple-csv-to-multiple-worksheet-in-a-single-workbook) thread to do the importing

```
Sub ImportCSVs()
Dim fPath   As String
Dim fCSV    As String
Dim wbCSV   As Workbook
Dim wbMST   As Workbook
Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
Set wbMST = ThisWorkbook
Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
    fPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End If
fPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1) & "\"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
fCSV = Dir(fPath & "\" & "*.csv")
On Error Resume Next
Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
    Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fCSV)
    wbMST.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Delete
    ActiveSheet.Move After:=wbMST.Sheets(wbMST.Sheets.Count)
    Columns.AutoFit
    fCSV = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set wbCSV = Nothing
End Sub
```

This does the importing but the delimiter in my csv files is semicolon and the script uses commas delimiter and the table gets messed up because comma is used in the headers of the table and as a decimal seperator. How can I change it?

Comment: This has been asked several times here. Excel uses the locale information set in Windows, so unless you are sure your data will match these settings, you are better off splitting the data yourself, and avoid Excel built-in CSV import.

Comment: Please try to define _format_ or/and _delimiter_ on the [.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) method

Comment: You can try using the `Workbooks.OpenText` method instead where you can define the delimiter. I seem to recall that, with some versions of Excel, you many need to change the file type from `.csv` to `.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

@Ron Rosenfeld Thank you, this worked. Now I just need to change all my data files to .txt.

```
Sub ImportCSVs()
Dim fPath   As String
Dim fCSV    As String  
Dim wbCSV   As Workbook
Dim wbMST   As Workbook
Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
Set wbMST = ThisWorkbook
Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
fPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End If
fPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1) & "\"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
fCSV = Dir(fPath & "\" & "*.txt")
On Error Resume Next
Do While Len(fCSV) > 0
Filename = fPath & fCSV
Workbooks.OpenText Filename:=Filename, DataType:=xlDelimited, Semicolon:=True, DecimalSeparator:=",", Comma:=False


wbMST.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name).Delete
ActiveSheet.Move After:=wbMST.Sheets(wbMST.Sheets.Count)
Columns.AutoFit
fCSV = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set wbCSV = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Sub CombineTextFiles()

    Dim xFilesToOpen As Variant
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xTempWb As Workbook
    Dim xDelimiter As String
    Dim xScreen As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xDelimiter = "|"
    xFilesToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSV Files (*.csv), *.csv", , "Kutools for Excel", , True)
    If TypeName(xFilesToOpen) = "Boolean" Then
        MsgBox "No files were selected", , ""
        GoTo ExitHandler
    End If
    I = 1
    Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
    xTempWb.Sheets(1).Copy
    Set xWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    xTempWb.Close False
    xWb.Worksheets(I).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, OtherChar:="|"
    Do While I < UBound(xFilesToOpen)
        I = I + 1
        Set xTempWb = Workbooks.Open(xFilesToOpen(I))
        With xWb
            xTempWb.Sheets(1).Move after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            .Worksheets(I).Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
              Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
              TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
              ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
              Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, _
              Comma:=False, Space:=False, _
              Other:=True, OtherChar:=xDelimiter
        End With
    Loop
ExitHandler:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
    Set xWb = Nothing
    Set xTempWb = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, , "Excel"
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```